# Newsletter showing wrong election date

Tags: bug, election, newsletter

At [Drones.SE](https://drones.stackexchange.com/), we are holding our [first moderator election](https://drones.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).

I got the newsletter for Drones today and it had this at the top:

[image: newsletter]

This is a great advertisement for the election but the dates are wrong. **Nominations close on the 25th and voting closes on the 2nd June**.

Comment: @mindstormsboi If it was written by a person, one of the best places to tell them is on MSE. Here.